# How to use esc_attr__() function properly to translate a variable that contains string?

Tags: theme-development, localization, validation, sanitization

I am trying to develop a theme and trying to escape a string using `esc_attr__()` fuction. Here is how I implemented it.

```
$title = stoic_get_the_site_title();
echo esc_attr__($title, 'stoic');
```

But Themecheck plugin is giving me this error:

```
WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function esc_attr__, with the arguments 'stoic'
```

What is the proper way to do it so that Themecheck doesn't show this type of error?

Comment: contact the author of the plugin and tell him to improve his error messages. As for the question itself, this is like not doing any research at all, which is why the downvote. You just do not do such things, end of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have static text with dynamic content then you can use.

`printf( esc_attr___('static text goes here with %s', 'text-domain' ), $title );`

If you have only $title then no need to translate it.

Just escape it.

`echo esc_attr( $title );`

---

Note `esc_attr`, `esc_attr__` and `esc_attr_e` used for escaping dynamic values from HTML element attributes.

E.g.

`` `<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">` ``

And `esc_html`, `esc_html__` and `esc_html_e` used for escaping dynamic values from HTML content.

E.g.

```
<div> <?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?> </div>
```

Comment: What? There is no need to translate $title. He can escape it but could not translate.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

Comment: sorry, you are right, but he wants to translate the title, your code is correct  but do not translate it